# Find Alerts on the page and close them if there were in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, alert, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE and Stack Overflow.
I want to find any alerts on the page and close them, in Selenium IDE.

When I try to check whether there are alerts on the page, if there aren't any, then it works well. But if the page has any alerts, I can't check them. I need to press alerts via the `getAlert` command, but if page doesn't have any alerts, then `getAlert` fails my test case.

I need do this in one TestCase:
Continue to execute my code. After checking whether the page has an alert or not, I don't know whether there will be an alert or not, sometimes I have alerts on the page, sometimes not.

```
storeAlertPresent(alert_value)
getAlert
```

This is working if the page has an alert, but doesn't work if the page has no alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You could build in a condition with a boolean which checks if alert is present. Then say that if alert is present, accept the alert, else nothing.

Comment: Yes it is need me, but do it to Selenium is difficult. Can you give me some example?

Comment: Try the following:  public boolean isAlertPresent() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        driver.switchTo().alert(); 
        return true; 
    }   // try 
    catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }   // catch 
}

Comment: And how I should it in the Selenium IDE?? I need solution in Selenium IDE.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.nl/2013/06/selenium-for-testing-alert-on-page.html